# How can I pass props value to input in React without getting error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have my update modal where I want to pass values from props to the current employee data but when I do like this I get an error, I searched on google everyone uses like onChange in input but the effect is only visible when a user starts typing something I need to be visible when user click to update modal button

```
Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

```js
import React from 'react';

function UpdateModal(props){
    const currentEmployeeData = props.employeeData;

    function updateEmployeeData(){

    }
    
    return (
        <div className="modal fade" id={"updateModal"+ props.modalId} tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="updateModalLabel">Employee Update</h5>
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <form className="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="Employee Name">Employee Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="employeeName" id="employeeName" className="form-control" value={currentEmployeeData.employee_name ?? ""} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="Employee Salary">Employee Salary:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="employeeSalary" id="employeeSalary" className="form-control" value={currentEmployeeData.salary ?? ""} />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" className="btn btn-info" onClick={updateEmployeeData} />
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateModal;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a controlled `input` with `value`, you also need to use `onChange` event to update the value.

```js
import React from 'react';

function UpdateModal(props){
    const currentEmployeeData = props.employeeData;

    function updateEmployeeData(){

    }
    
    return (
        <div className="modal fade" id={"updateModal"+ props.modalId} tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="updateModalLabel">Employee Update</h5>
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <form className="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="Employee Name">Employee Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="employeeName" id="employeeName" className="form-control" value={currentEmployeeData.employee_name ?? ""} onChange={() => {
                          // update emplyee_name value here.
                        }} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="Employee Salary">Employee Salary:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="employeeSalary" id="employeeSalary" className="form-control" value={currentEmployeeData.salary ?? ""} onChange={() => {
                          // update salary value here.
                        }} />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" className="btn btn-info" onClick={updateEmployeeData} />
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateModal;
```

If you want to set just a default value, then don't use `value`, but use `defaultValue` property.

```js
import React from 'react';

function UpdateModal(props){
    const currentEmployeeData = props.employeeData;

    function updateEmployeeData(){

    }
    
    return (
        <div className="modal fade" id={"updateModal"+ props.modalId} tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="updateModalLabel">Employee Update</h5>
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <form className="form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="Employee Name">Employee Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="employeeName" id="employeeName" className="form-control" defaultValue={currentEmployeeData.employee_name ?? ""}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="Employee Salary">Employee Salary:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="employeeSalary" id="employeeSalary" className="form-control" defaultValue={currentEmployeeData.salary ?? ""}/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" className="btn btn-info" onClick={updateEmployeeData} />
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateModal;
```